# Why am I getting duplicate from this join statement?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am having two tables for email and phone number storage. Both of those tables do have a reference to a `shop` by their columns `shop_id`.

What I want is to fetch all emails from a shop with id = 1 and further fetch the phone numbers from the same shop.

```
SELECT 
    shop_contact_phone.id, 
    shop_contact_phone.shop_id, 
    number, tbl.email
FROM (
    SELECT * 
    FROM shop_contact_email 
    WHERE shop_id = 1
    ) AS tbl
JOIN 
    shop_contact_phone 
ON (shop_contact_phone.shop_id = tbl.shop_id);
```

However, I am getting duplicate entries back. What am I doing wrong here?

Here is my [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e63f0/3).

Comment: 1) Subquery is redundant 2) Prepare http://sqlfiddle.com with sample data and desired result

Comment: You are getting duplicates because some shops have multiple phone numbers and/or multiple emails.  Sample data and desired results would clarify what you want to do in these cases.

Comment: @lad2025 Put a link to my question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I think I just realized that what I might not work the way I think it works ^^

Comment: Like Gordon Linoff suggested, you have two email addresses and two telephone numbers for shop 1 and you get the cartesian product of those, which makes 4 rows. How you do want to present the data instead?

Comment: @Patrick Yeah I see the problem now. It won't work the way I want it. I'll have to create two separate fetches here. It started with a 1-to-1 relation but now it's a 1-to-N relation of course.

Comment: @displayname Depending what resultset you want you could use `string_agg` [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d53d9/7/0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a *list* of the phone numbers and emails, use `union all` instead of `join`:

```
select sce.shop_id, 'email' as contacttype, sce.email
from shop_contact_email sce
where sce.shop_id = 1
union all
select scp.shop_id, 'phone', scp.number
from shop_contact_phone scp
where scp.shop_id = 1;
```

This puts them on separate rows.  You could also aggregate them into strings or arrays, depending on your need.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I didn't know that there is a `union all` instruction! :)